# Parsing URI parameters in a RESTful API

Tags: java, rest, uri, apache-commons, url-parameters

How should I approach parsing URI parameters in a REST API. For example:

```
http://api.example.com/item/ [{{ItemID}} [/{{Property}}]]
```

The following requests should all be valid:

```
http://api.example.com/item
http://api.example.com/item/
http://api.example.com/item/1
http://api.example.com/item/1/
http://api.example.com/item/1/description
http://api.example.com/item/1/description/
```

I need to be able to get the ItemID and Property values, if they exist.

I attempted to use Apache Commons StringUtils and the substringBefore/substringAfter, but things soon got confusing. Is there a library for such a task, or another way I overlooked?

Comment: Is there a way to turn off java syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely appreciate @Jagdeep's answer, but since I am not using JAX-RS, I couldn't use it. After doing some research, it was clear that there weren't any libraries to do this, so I decided to create my own. It is very crude, and has no documentation as of now. However, I will update this soon. You are welcome to submit a pull request to me, with improvements.

https://github.com/ArjMart/UrlParser

Usage:

```
UrlParser parser = new Parser();
parser.setTemplate("/item/{INT:itemID}/{STRING:itemAttribute}");
UrlParametersMap upm = parser.parse(request.getURI());
boolean attributeExists = upm.parameterExists("itemAttribute");
String attribute = null;
if(attributeExists){
  attribute = upm.getString("itemAttribute");
}
```

Disclaimer:
I am (obviously) affiliated with UrlParser as I am its sole creator and contributor.

Comment: @OscarPerez oh. I didn't see that :) Well that's how competition is created I guess...

Comment: indeed! the more the merrier :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAX-RS, you can do something like

```
@GET
@Path("/{param1}/{param2}")
@Produces("text/plain")

public String get(@PathParam("param1") int param1, @PathParam("param2") int param2) {

    logger.debug("\n param1 = " + param1 + " .. param2 = " + param2);
}
```

Comment: As of now I am just using the Servlet 3.0 API, but if needed, I will switch to JAX-RS